# Difference between reactions of ring strained cycloalkanes and higher cycloalkanes (n>4)

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides

Today I read two publications stating that cyclopropane's ring can be opened by reactions of it with $\ce{Cl2/Br2/HCl/HBr}$. Correct me please if I interpreted something wrong.

Here are these publications:

1. Lee, C. C.; Hahn, B.; Wan, K.; Woodcock, D. J. Reactions of cyclopropane with hydrochloric acid and of bromocyclopropane with hydrobromic acid. *J. Org. Chem.* **1969,** *34* (10), 3210–3211. [DOI: 10.1021/jo01262a097](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01262a097).
2. Lambert, J. B.; Chelius, E. C.; Schulz, W. J.; Carpenter, N. E. Polar bromination and chlorination of cyclopropane. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1990,** *112* (8), 3156–3162. [DOI: 10.1021/ja00164a043](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja00164a043).

I read as well that cyclopropane has extra reactivity (due to ring strain obviously) so in the light, it behaves like a linear alkane getting substituted but in the absence of light, ring gets opened (as shown in a [ChemGuide article](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/organicprops/alkanes/halogenation.html).

Here are my questions about ring-strained cycloalkanes:

- can be ring-opening agents for cyclopropane used for cyclobutane?
- can we open ring-strained cycloalkanes with hydrogen (and catalyst of course)?
- can we substitute cyclobutane like a cyclopropane? (in light)

But, still, I got a few questions about higher cycloalkanes' chemistry

- does hydrogen with catalyst open higher cycloalkanes' rings?
- in the reaction of $\ce{Cl2/Br2}$ with higher cycloalkanes ($n>4$), ring gets opened or compound is substituted?
- do higher cycloalkanes ($n>4$) even react with $\ce{HCl/HBr}$?